# In GitHub Actions, is it possible to access the name of a deleted branch?

Tags: github-actions

It is possible to have a GitHub Action trigged by [the `delete` event](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#delete-event-delete). However, according to those, the `GITHUB_REF` variable then points to the *default* branch, rather than the branch that was deleted. (Likewise for [the `push` event](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#push-event-push).)

Is it possible to obtain the name of the branch that was deleted? Specifically, I'd like to clean up a deployment with the branch name's ID that was created in response to the `push` event.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can access `github.event.ref` and `github.event.ref_type` from the github context.

The event will trigger when other ref types are deleted, too. So you need to filter just `branch` deletions.

```
name: Branch Deleted
on: delete
jobs:
  delete:
    if: github.event.ref_type == 'branch'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Clean up
        run: |
          echo "Clean up for branch ${{ github.event.ref }}"
```

Comment: Are the variables `github.event.*` populate from the content of the file `$GITHUB_EVENT_PATH`? How come they are not environment variables like the others?

Comment: The `github.event.*` context is the event payload. You can see an example of the payload in the documentation [here](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/event-payloads/#delete). Every event has a payload like this that is accessible during the workflow via the `github.event` context. Yes, I'm fairly sure the file content at `GITHUB_EVENT_PATH` is the same payload. It wouldn't be sensible for GitHub to turn every property of the payload into environment variables. There would be too many.