# In GitHub Actions, is it possible to access the last commit-id of a deleted branch?

Tags: github-actions

It is possible to have a GitHub Action trigged by the delete event. However, according to those, the GITHUB_REF variable then points to the default branch, rather than the branch that was deleted. (Likewise for the push event.)

Is it possible to get the last commit-id of the branch that was deleted?

Comment: Do you really need the last *commit* id or just the branch name? Branch name is available as "github.event.ref" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62281418/in-github-actions-is-it-possible-to-access-the-name-of-a-deleted-branch

Comment: I really need  last commit id of deleted branch.

Comment: Thing is, if it's not recorded in the gh event details (it isn't), it's not trivial to find it in any other way in actions. Locally, git reflog (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640764/can-i-recover-a-branch-after-its-deletion-in-git) is a solution, but that's kind of manual inspection and the commits are not linked to a branch name, and I don't think reflog contains anything in the fresh GH actions workspace anyway.

Comment: Thanks, but yes there is no way to get last commit id of a deleted branch.